# IMFStreamSink::ProcessSample() not being called on a custom media sink

Tags: c++, uwp, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to implement a custom Windows Media Foundation media sink for use in a UWP application that will use it via `MediaCapture::PrepareLowLagRecordToCustomSinkAsync()`.

However, I am currently running into an issue where the `ProcessSample()` function of my `IMFStreamSink` is never called, even though I queue the event in my `IMFMediaSink::OnClockStart()`.

I have followed the documentation here ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-sinks ) and also taken a look at the "Simple Communication" sample.

Here is the output that I am getting, I have logged every function call and the HRESULT of every call that my sinks execute:

```
MyCaptureMediaSink::SetPresentationClock        
OK: Clock->AddClockStateSink(this)
MyCaptureStreamSink::BeginGetEvent        
OK: MediaEventQueue->BeginGetEvent(pCallback, punkState)
MyCaptureMediaSink::OnClockStart        
MyCaptureStreamSink::QueueEvent        
OK: MediaEventQueue->QueueEventParamVar(met, guidExtendedType, hrStatus, pvValue)
OK: Sink->QueueEvent(MEStreamSinkStarted, GUID_NULL, S_OK, nullptr)
MyCaptureStreamSink::QueueEvent        
OK: MediaEventQueue->QueueEventParamVar(met, guidExtendedType, hrStatus, pvValue)
OK: Sink->QueueEvent(MEStreamSinkRequestSample, GUID_NULL, S_OK, nullptr)
```

What I think I should be seeing after the last line is a call to `MyCaptureStreamSink::EndGetEvent()` due to `MEStreamSinkStarted` being received, followed by another `BeginGetEvent()` and `EndGetEvent()` pair and a call `ProcessSample()` because the next event would be the `MEStreamSinkRequestSample` event.

Am I missing some functions that I still need to call in order to get a call to these functions by the MediaCapture system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem:
I re-implemented my stream sink without using `winrt::implements`, which seems to work as intended. What I assume (I'm still not 100% sure, though) is happening is that since `IMFStreamSink` derives from `IMFMediaGenerator`, the `winrt::implemnets` does not generate the `QueryInterface` properly for the base type. In my own implementation, I need to explicitly handle it.

This is the old class declaration, which doesn't work:

```
class MyStreamSink : public winrt::implements<MyStreamSink, IMFStreamSink>
{
    // ...
};
```

and this is the class that works:

```
class MyStreamSink: public IMFStreamSink
{
    virtual HRESULT QueryInterface(const IID& riid, void** ppvObject) override
    {
        if (riid == __uuidof(IMFMediaEventGenerator))
        {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<IMFMediaEventGenerator*>(this);
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be `public winrt::implements<MyStreamSink, IMFStreamSink, IMFMediaEventGenerator >`

Answer (score 0):

An even better approach would be to override winrt::is_guid_of. By this approach you get one shared v-table and not two separate v-tables. For more information: [How do I use C++/WinRT to implement a classic COM interface that derives from another classic COM interface](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200424-00/?p=103702)

```
template<>
inline bool winrt::is_guid_of<IMFStreamSink>(guid const& id) noexcept
{
    return winrt::is_guid_of<IMFStreamSink, IMFMediaEventGenerator>(id);
}

class MyStreamSink : public winrt::implements<MyStreamSink, IMFStreamSink>
{
    //...
};
```